# Commit failed (details follow): MKCOL not allowed

Tags: svn, github, versions

I using versions and github. But when I trying to making the first commit after create a folder inside bookmark, Its said : Commit failed (details follow): MKCOL not allowed

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Please give an advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Please give an advice.

You are using Subversion client to access GitHub, that's what's wrong. While GitHub offers "compatibility with Subversion clients" through some custom proxy engine, it does not mean that it's going work with all SVN clients.

Use Git client to access GitHub.

Comment: Man this help me so much

Comment: Just came back after I notice that I did not press accept this answer 6 years ago. Thank you for your answer!